Create a normal distribution sampling in Geometry Nodes
I want to generate a random distribution of numbers and then arrange/stack them so you can see the normal distribution.
At the moment I simply use the Random Value node to show the effect/workflow I am using.
I use this node setup

To get this output

At the moment they are binned to 5-values (That's what the multiply by 20 is doing).
Anyway to easily replace the random sample node with some normal distribution looking function? Doesn't need to be exact.
EDIT: For now I'm using this nodegroup
https://blenderartists.org/t/normal-gaussian-distribution-node/1356631

